# How to remove the Points of Interest from a Windows Phone 8.1 MapControl?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, bing-maps

So here is my map view:

[image]

How can I remove all these S-es and U-s and such data from the map and actually clear it?

Comment: I think that this is built in and you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8.1 map control doesn't have an option for turning this off. There was however an option added to the Windows 10 map control to disable these called BussinessLandmarksVisible.

Migrating your Windows Phones 8.1 app to Windows 10 would be fairly easy. The map control is backwards compatible and has the new features. These apps also work on all other Windows 10 devices besides phone. You will likely want to target Windows 10 soon. It won't be long before it has a larger market share than Windows 8/8.1 (maybe a couple months).